# How to check whether a select variable has a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a select statement and i assigned that select statement to a variable @var1
now i have to check whether a column  has value or not using @var1 is it possible?

```
SET @STRVAR1='SELECT  type, a.groupnumber, idnumber, relation,a.code,  flag, planname, a.insurancename, address1, address2, REPLACE(zipcode,-,'') AS zipcode, cityName, statecode,c.PrintBillProTaxonomy  FROM  TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3  WHERE  b.citycode=c.citycode and a.insurancecode = c.insurancecode  AND  Code = ''PT0000'' AND  a.No =  ''GT56789'' AND  a.Flag = ''SAMPLE''' 
    EXEC (@STRVAR1)
```

MY CONDITION SHOULD BE:

```
IF @STRVAR.COLUMNNAME<>''
BEGIN
PRINT'TEXT'
END
```

Comment: not possible without executing it

Comment: IF I EXECUTE IT WILL IT BE POSSIBLE?

Comment: yes. But your query won't run. there are syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the results of your query in a temp table or a table variable and then query that table:

Example below using a table variable:

```
declare @t1 table (type varchar(10), groupnumber int, idnumber int, etc....) 
-- you need to declare all your resultset columns here and their respective types 

declare @strvar1 nvarchar(max)
SET @strvar1='SELECT type, a.groupnumber, idnumber, relation,a.code,  flag, planname, a.insurancename, address1, address2, REPLACE(zipcode,-,'') AS zipcode, cityName, statecode,c.PrintBillProTaxonomy  
              FROM  TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3  
              WHERE  b.citycode=c.citycode and a.insurancecode = c.insurancecode  AND  Code = ''PT0000'' AND a.No =  ''GT56789'' AND a.Flag = ''SAMPLE''' 

insert into @t1
exec(@strvar1)
 
select * 
from @t1
where columnname <> ''
```

It would be good to change the join logic of your query into [modern proper join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).